# Branch link opens Ionic 3 app, which immediately closes before loading

Tags: ionic-framework, branch.io

I'm configuring Branch and seeing what I think is unexpected behavior upon trying to test my setup. I have an Ionic 3.7 app and am new to Ionic/iOS/Android development- so I've been following the Branch docs to try and get this configured (just for iOS right now).

What I've done so far:

1. I started with this guide: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/cordova/
2. The pre-requisite is that Universal Links are setup, which makes sense. In order to get that working, I clicking the link in the guide above, which took me to this guide: https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/guide/cordova/
3. The Universal Link steps have gone fine until #3, where I'm trying to verify that my setup is correct. I created a Quick Link and texted it to my phone (which had a build of my app that I ran after adding the config in step 2).
4. Clicking the link starts to open the app (I see the splash screen), but it closes before loading is complete (I see a black screen momentarily). When I open this build of the app normally, it loads and runs normally

As I mentioned, I'm new to this- do I need to follow the Apple Universal Link setup (from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)) with the `apple-app-site-association` file before starting the Branch config? I didn't see any mention of that in the guides I followed- however, it may be something so basic that it's assumed the user has done it already.

Regardless, I did configure that file and make it available as the Apple guide says. I'm still seeing the same behavior when I click my Branch link.

The 2nd Branch guide I posted only mentions that the app opens immediately without routing through Safari as a result of the test- is what I'm seeing actually correct? I don't have the SDK installed to handle the links, so I could see that being the case too.

**UPDATE**

I went ahead and installed the SDK, following the instructions here. It was somewhat confusing, as I wasn't sure if I should be supplementing the additions to `config.xml` from my step 1) above, or if my `branch-config` section should *only* have the keys from the SDK installation example.

I ended up commenting out the changes to `config.xml` from step 1) and it looks like it worked, as I now see the deeplink data when opening the app via the Quick Link I created before. I had previously added the domains to my entitlements file directly in Xcode before, though, so I'm now wondering if I need those extra config keys in order to persist the entitlements changes should I need to remove/readd the iOS platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io) here:

You can follow the iconic integration guide available on Github [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking#getting-started).You need to update your config.xml with the Branch key assigned to your App, which can be found on the Account Settings page of the Branch dashboard. The URI scheme is the one you have defined in the Link Settings page of the Branch dashboard and the link domain for your Branch links is also defined on the Link Settings Page.

If you still have issues, I would recommend writing to `integrations@branch.io`.

Comment: Thanks Amruta!

I had followed the integration guide from Github- my questions were around whether those were the only steps, or if I needed to follow the additional setup I found in other Branch documentation. I ended up getting it working after following these guides, setting up the right file on my webserver, and then tweaking the Xcode project to support Universal Links.